# British citizenship of adopted son. I'm British by birth and live in America

Tags: usa, united-kingdom, citizenship, dual-citizenship, children

I am a British citizen by birth and a US permanent resident holder. Last year my husband and I adopted my stepdaughters baby, who has lived with us since his birth. Is he entitled to British citizenship? Is it automatic or do I need to apply?

Answer (score 3):

It looks like it is possible that your son can gain British citizenship, but you will have to apply. From [Intercountry adoption and British citizenship](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/guidance-on-how-adopted-children-can-become-british/intercountry-adoption-and-british-citizenship):

> an application will normally be approved if each of the following criteria is satisfied:
>
> 1. at least one of the adoptive parents is a British citizen otherwise than by descent (i.e. by virtue of his or her birth, adoption, registration or naturalisation in the United Kingdom)
> 2. the adoptive parents have consented to the registration
> 3. there is no reason to refuse registration on grounds of the child’s character
> 4. the Home Secretary is satisfied that all relevant adoption laws have been complied with. This includes the laws of the country in which the adoption has taken place, the country of origin of the child and the country in which the adoptive parents are habitually resident
> 5. the Home Secretary is satisfied that the adoption is not one of convenience arranged to facilitate the child’s admission to the United Kingdom